# In VSCode, when use git compare to previous versions, can I revert one changes back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

Here is the screenshot of what I mean. As I am comparing my working file with previous commit, there are tons of changes. I can navigate to each of the changes by using up/under arrow in top-right corner. But for some changes, I want to revert it back to previous version, now I have to copy the contents from left to right. Is there a better way to do this? I remember pycharm used to have one-click to do this.
[image: Git diff]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the green zone in the right side of the diff: you should see a "Revert Selected Ranges" option.

[image]

Selecting that option would revert the right side to the left side content.